# Lost OCI card. Applying for an eVisa

Tags: india, e-visas

I had my UK passport and Indian OCI card stolen. I'm applying for an eVisa and answering the question whetherI have visited India previously means I need a visa number, which I don't have. Can I enter my OCI card number? I have a scanned copy of my OCI card, but not of my OCI visa on the UK passport. I think the numbers are the same but the alphabet is different. Thank you.